# specify columns from has many through association Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have three models.

```
User
has_many :boards through => :celebrations
has_many   :celebrations, :dependent => :destroy

Board
has_many   :celebrations, :dependent => :destroy
has_many  :users, :through => :celebrations do
           def by_role(role) 
           find(:all, :conditions => ["celebrations.role = ?", role])
           end
           end

Celebration
:belongs_to :user
:belongs_to :board
```

Celebration Table

```
   create_table :celebrations do |t|
      t.column :board_id,        :int, :null => false
      t.column :user_id,         :int, :null => false 
      t.column :role,            :string,  :null => false
      t.column :token,           :string
      t.column :accepted,    :boolean, :default => false
      t.timestamps
```

In the controller:

```
  @board = Board.find(session[:board_id])
    @friends = @board.users.by_role("FRIEND")
```

In the view:

```
<% for friend in @friends do %>
<%= friend.name %>
<%= friend.email %>
```

However when I do the following:

```
<% friend.celebration.accepted %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `celebration' for #<User:0x104788c00>
```

How can I access the column 'accepted' in the celebrations table returned along with the record using the model extension "by_role(role)".

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: what is the association between User and Celebration. `has_many` or `has_one`. You havent mentioned it in your code. I think it is `has_many` so you should call `friend.celebrations` and according to your need, call `friend.celebrations.first.accepted` or whatever.

Comment: Agreeing with @rubyprince, you're talking to the user (friend) object as though it were the many-to-one side in the relationship, but it's really the one-to-many side.

Comment: My appologies. I forgot the relationships. I guess I was trying to avoid another database hit and apply eager loading. I was hoping to have a query that will return all the data from the Users table and the column 'accepted' from the celebrations table. Then access the info as friend.celebrations.accepted.  Is there a way to do this using eager loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load the celebrations like this:

Board model:

```
Board
  has_many   :celebrations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many  :users, :through => :celebrations do
     def by_role(role) 
       find(:all, :conditions => ["celebrations.role = ?", role], :include => :celebrations)
     end
  end
```

With :include you will have one more hit:

```
Celebration Load (0.2ms) SELECT celebrations.* FROM celebrations WHERE (celebrations.user_id IN (5,6))
```

that loads the celebrations data for users. 
This will avoid in this particular case two hits that would be needed to retrieve celebrations for each user. If you have 10 users you will end with one hit instead of 10.

Eager loading loads all the data you will need to cycle through in association with one query instead of n queries.

The problem remains for the accepted data because you will have an array of celebrations due to the has_many relationship with user.

You can use something like this:

```
<% friend.celebrations.map{|celeb| celeb.accepted }.join(",") %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tommasop. I will give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, Tommasop, I did exactly as described above and I get the identical output from the terminal.  Meaning the same hits to the database. Maybe eagerloading was occuring?

Comment: I have added the database hits above. I would really appreciate your feedback on this so I can get an understanding of eagerloading etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can see that with :include you have one more hit: Celebration Load (0.2ms)   SELECT `celebrations`.* FROM `celebrations` WHERE (`celebrations`.user_id IN (5,6)) that loads the celebrations data for users. This will avoid in this particular case two hits that would be needed to retrieve celebrations for each user. If you have 10 users you will end with one hit instead of 10.

Comment: you had better modify your question and not my answer ;)